# How to update a variable declared in a different class?

Tags: java, variables

Hello I am working on this homework and it's almost done but one thing doesn't work well. I created these two classes "SavingAccount" and "TimeAccount", subclasses of "Account" and they have different type of interest calculations that includes current time and time that account last updated. I have a time variable which is modeled as months and it's declared as zero in my Test class. And whenever i deposit, withdraw or transfer money it should update the accounts lastTimeUpdated variable. But it doesn't work. 
Here are my deposit and withdraw methods in Account class

```
protected int currentTime = Test.month;
protected int timeUpdated;    

public abstract double getBalance();

public void withdraw(double amount){
    if(amount <= balance){
        balance = this.getBalance();
        balance -= amount;
        timeUpdated = currentTime;
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Not enough funds...");
}

public void deposit(double amount){
    balance = this.getBalance();
    balance += amount;
    timeUpdated = currentTime;
}
```

And my overridden getBalance() methods for subclasses;
SavingAccount:

```
    @Override
    public double getBalance() {
        double a = (1+term*interestRate/12);
        double b = (currentTime-timeUpdated)/term;
        balance = balance*Math.pow(a,b);
        return balance;
    }
```

TimeAccount:

```
    public double getBalance(){
        double a = 1+interestRate/12;
        double b = currentTime-timeUpdated;
        balance = balance*Math.pow(a,b);
        return balance;
    }
```

And in my test class there is this month variable with click() method which increments month. I used it but time doesn't get updated in my Account classes.

```
public static int month = 0;

static void click(){
    month++;
    System.out.println("Current month is " + month);
}

static void click(int x){
    month += x;
    System.out.println("Current month is " + month);
}
```

So my problem is i can't update the time in accounts, that's why interest doesn't work and balance remains same. Thanks in advance.

Edit: My question is marked "duplicate". But i couldn't find the answer in other questions. So `month` shouldn't be `static` in my test class? Then how can i use `click()` method in my main method?

Comment: This question is not really the same problem. There is no inheritance problem or hiding here. The OP has a design problem on how to initialise and further update a value in a class. Why are you so prompt to closing?

Comment: I didn't get how would the answer in other question help me.